# Continuous SVN Diff with Jenkins/Hudson/Teamcity/etc

Tags: svn, hudson, integration, jenkins, continuous

After some searching around the web I want to seek your opinion on this topic...

I have to monitor developers on many branches in SVN against Trunk. One of the ways I would like to do this is diff between the branch and trunk every night and report the differences. I do not want to necessarily merge back in every night but I want early feedback on the deviations between the two locations.

I have thought about doing a simplistic svn diff between trunk and the branch and emailing that around. However ideally what I would like is a tool that would take this output and convert it into a HTML Website that would then show the differences in a nice easily accessible way

I have looked for a tool like this but found nothing that matched

Any ideas would be great!!!

Comment: svn diff --xml + cron + some post-processing of XML?

Comment: thats what I have. Although havent found a new post processor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such tool. All you can do is write such diff viewer by yourself or adapt to your needs existing web-based diff viewers, such as [websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) or [viewvc](http://www.viewvc.org/).

Actually, sending diffs via email is not a bad idea at all. You might install appropriate diff viewer ([freediff](http://www.freediff.com/), [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) or any other; full list of popular diff viewers you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool)) on your machine and create corresponding association between app and `.diff` extension. You will be able to open diffs directly from your e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is get a continuous build tool like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org).

Jenkins takes care of all that *web stuff* for you. All you need to do is create a shell script to do the diffs for you. Then, you create a Jenkins job that runs once per day instead of after each and every build. Jenkins will run your script and display it in an easy to access webpage. Even better, the history of each run is stored and can be accessed.

It takes about an hour to set Jenkins up from scratch and figure out how to get it to work. This is much easier than rolling your own code. And now that you have Jenkins, you can implement continuous builds and testing..